# desing the database for survey app with various types of answers

Tags: mysql, database-design, php

I have to create a survey app for which answers should be stored in the database. I created an html form containing some questions (about 30) with various types of answers (check boxes, radio buttons, auto-complete, etc). Now, I am going to design my database.

First, I thought of only 3 tables : Questions, Answers, Users . However after I searched some similar questions such as :[Database design for a survey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764435/database-design-for-a-survey?rq=1), [db design - survey/quiz with questions and answers [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540885/db-design-survey-quiz-with-questions-and-answers) I found some other design models e.g creating 4 tables : Questions, PossibleAnswers, UsersAnswers and Users. Now, I have these questions:

- Should I create a survey table too ? (at this moment,there is only
  one survey for my app, but not sure about the future.)
- Which design model would be better in my case?
- In case of using the first model, should I create specific column for
  each types of answer? (for instance, consider this question: which
  are your favorite movie genres? and it has more than 10 possible
  answers! then if I want to create a column for each possible answers
  of all questions, it would be lots of columns!)
- In case of the second model, is it correct? (this is what I
  understood from other similar questions, but still I am not sure if
  it is useful form me and if yes, what is the advantage of this
  model?)

  **Questions**: *questionId, question*

  **PossibleAnswers**: *possibleanswerId, questionId, possibleanswer*

  **UsersAnswers**: *useranswerId, possibleanswerId, userId, answer*

  **Users**: *userId, username, password*

I really appreciate all your ideas and suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have the Survey table as it will be much easier to add it now than later on when your app is live.

The second model is much better as it provides the flexibility to have multiple possible answers and user answers for a single question in a normalised fashion. Having a column for each answer is not a good idea.

Comment: thanks James, so in case of the second model, my question is that what could be the possible columns for "PossibleAnswers" table? since for instance my first question if of type checkbox and it has about 10 possible answer.. how could I manage it for all the questions?

Comment: Something like: possible_answer_id, question_id, answer_text, display_order. The last one would be used to order the possible selection for a radio group question

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just didn't get what exactly the last column means, I mean whay I need order for radio button answers? :(

Comment: If you had the following values for your answers it would make sense: 0, 1-5, 6-10, 11-15